# Watson Studio Solution Failed Unknown

Tags: ibm-watson, opl

Seeking help identifying the reason for my solution to have failed. Here is the log file:

```
[2021-04-13T07:56:27Z, INFO] Initialization of Arcs.
[2021-04-13T07:56:27Z, INFO] Initialization of TArcs.
[2021-04-13T07:56:27Z, INFO] Initialization of Nodes.
[2021-04-13T07:56:27Z, INFO] Initialization of TNodes.
[2021-04-13T07:56:27Z, INFO] Initialization of TotalCost.
[2021-04-13T07:56:27Z, INFO] Initialization of SelectArc.
[2021-04-13T07:56:27Z, INFO] Initialization of StartServiceTime.
[2021-04-13T07:56:27Z, WARNING] Effective number of workers to be used for solve has been updated to: '1' (original value was: '0')
[2021-04-13T07:56:27Z, INFO] Version identifier: 12.10.0.0 | 2020-01-09 | 0d94640
[2021-04-13T07:56:27Z, INFO] CPXPARAM_Threads                                 1
[2021-04-13T07:56:27Z, INFO] Presolve time = 0.00 sec. (0.00 ticks)
[2021-04-13T07:56:27Z, INFO] Root node processing (before b&c):
[2021-04-13T07:56:27Z, INFO] Real time             =    0.00 sec. (0.00 ticks)
[2021-04-13T07:56:27Z, INFO] Sequential b&c:
[2021-04-13T07:56:27Z, INFO] Real time             =    0.00 sec. (0.00 ticks)
[2021-04-13T07:56:27Z, INFO] ------------
[2021-04-13T07:56:27Z, INFO] Total (root+branch&cut) =    0.00 sec. (0.00 ticks)
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue.

Fix: linearizing the non-linear constraints. I am surprised because Version identifier: 12.10.0.0 should be able to handle non-linear constraints.